# Dynamically serializing composite objects

Tags: java, serialization

Consider the below class:

```
class CompositeObject{

String id;

Object obj;
String classType

}
```

When I want to serialize the composite object, is there a way if i can plug in a different type of serializer to serialize "obj" than the serializer used for composite object? The type of serializer to be used for "obj" is stored in the "classType" variable and is known only at run time. [I cannot annotate the serializer class to be used for Obj].

Comment: While I'm not sure about using the Java built-in serialization capability, you might look into JAXB. I've done similar things using JAXB and an XML schema, where the type of object to be serialized/deserialized is determined using an `xsi:type=` attribute and is not necessarily known at runtime.

Comment: I am looking at a JSON serializer.

Comment: Then you should look up Jackson for Java, I think you could use a Custom Serializer here.